# Clang-format installed via Cygwin won't run

Tags: cygwin, clang, clang-format

When I try running `clang-format` in the Cygwin64 terminal, I get the following output:

```
$ clang-format
: CommandLine Error: Option 'disable-symbolication' registered more than once!
LLVM ERROR: inconsistency in registered CommandLine options
```

I also cannot run it in Git Bash, getting the following output:

```
$ clang-format
      1 [main] clang-format (2208) C:\cygwin64\bin\clang-format.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x180301410/0x1802FD410.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
```

I only have one `cygwin1.dll` in `C:\cygwin64\bin`, and rebooting doesn't help.

`clang --version` gives:

```
$ clang --version
clang version 5.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_501/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-windows-cygnus
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

Comment: same here. It seems a package build error. You should report the problem on the cygwin mailing list.

Comment: done for you http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2018-05/msg00237.html

Comment: @matzeri thanks!!!!

Comment: just updated yesterday, error is still there (or an identical error has re-appeared).  reverting to clang 4.... hmm... says `Solution 2/2 (default)
  - do not ask to deinstall libclang5.0-5.0.1-2` ... oh dear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not much of an answer, but it's what I ended up doing.  And it was a little tricky, so I'm going to document it here.

Note, I actually downgraded doxygen, because the latest was dependent on clang-format-5

```
Uninstall clang 5.0.1-2
Uninstall doxygen 1.8.14-2 (automatically added)
Uninstall libclang5.0 5.0.1-2
Uninstall vim-clang-format 4.0.1-1
Install doxygen 1.8.13-3
```

Then (press Back)

```
Uninstall clang 5.0.1-2 (automatically added)
Uninstall doxygen 1.8.13-3 (automatically added)
Install clang 4.0.1-1
Install doxygen 1.8.13-3
```

After all that, although there is no-longer an entry for clang-format, I clang-format-4.0.1 is on my computer and operational.

Comment: thanks! Marking this as answer since it works, however the Cygwin/Clang team still has not resolved this

Comment: I also met this problem, but I don't have doxygen installed anyway. Do I install doxygen firstly and then downgrade it to work around this issue?